# Mysql UPDATE Cell value based on another cell id

Tags: mysql

The title do not describe my problem correctly, but i didnt know how else ill put it..

ill try to explain better here...

Im not close to be good with mysql so please have that in mind while explaining :P

i have a table called 'person' that look like this:

```
id  name    country father_id
52  bob     NULL    68 
68  joe     Maui    72
53  mia     NULL    68
51  robbie  NULL    68
```

I would now like to run a query directly in the database to UPDATE all person.id with the same country as their father_id

so the person table will look like this:

```
id  name    country father_id
52  bob     Maui    68 
68  joe     Maui    72
53  mia     Maui    68
51  robbie  Maui    68
```

so my problem is how i do the update based on the person.id's father_id's country... phew :P

Hope someone can help me put :D

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with an `update` statement and a correlated subquery:

```
update person
    set country = (select country from person p2 where person.father_id = p2.id)
    where father_id is not null;
```

EDIT:

I was trying to keep it simple, forgetting that MySQL requires an extra layer of subqueries, and then these don't work for the correlation.  The above is standard SQL that MySQL does not support.

So you do have to use a `join` in this case:

```
update person p join
       person father
       on p.father_id = father.id
    set p.country = father.country;
```

Comment: #1093 - You can't specify target table 'person' for update in FROM clause

Comment: @CMilla . . . Thank you very much.  I edited the answer.  I was trying to keep it on the simple side.

Comment: If you dont mind i have another question.. :P

If i want to update the person based on a cell value from mother_id AND father_id, how do i do that?

ex mother and father have a cell value 'clear' and i want the child to update with the same value

Comment: @CMilla . . . Ask another question, with sample data and desired results.  This is referring to two different parent records, so the query will be different.  (If you were just referring to the mother record, then it would be quite similar.)

Answer (score 0):

try this, I am a oracle but its the main idea

```
update person p1 set p1.country = (select (country) from person p2 where p2.id = p1.father_id)
```

Comment: i may be dumb as h... right now, but am i supposed to change the p1 and p2 to something? If not i get this error:
#1093 - You can't specify target table 'p1' for update in FROM clause

Comment: p1 and p2 are the alias try  update person as p1 set p1.country = (select (country) from person as p2 where p2.id = p1.father_id)